# Odd problem with trying to access Azure AD with Terraform through YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps, just from 1 specific project

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

This is an odd one.  We're using the following:

- Azure Devops for Projects/Repos/Pipelines
- Terraform to create azure resources, and interact with azure AD (trying various versions of
  AzureAD provider)
- YAML for pipeline code
- Service Principals or Managed Identities for Authentication to Azure
- Kubernetes Cluster hosting our build agents

We're getting the following error, when trying to run a pipeline from just 1 specific project:

**GroupsClient.BaseClient.Get(): unexpected status 400 with OData error:
│ BadRequest: Resource not found for the segment '**

The TF code we've created uses both azurerm and azuread providers.  We only get this error when it tries to do anything with the azuread provider, and ONLY in 1 project (same DevOps Organisation).

The Terraform and YAML code (the whole repo) has been copied to another 2 projects, and works fine.

I've also tried running with an existing Service Connection which did function originally within that Project, rather than the newly created Managed Identity within that project, but this now gives this same error 400.  All jobs are running on the same build agent.

It doesn't seem to be an authentication issue, as the code works in different projects, and the AzureRM code still functions either way.

As the TF code works in different projects, the service principals are working for some parts of the code, and the pipelines are identical as they are transferred with the TF code, I'm not sure adding the code would be helpful.

I've checked over the Project permissions, but I don't see how it can be a project specific permission, just tied to the azuread provider,  I would expect the entire code stack to fail if that were the case.

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Very annoying.  The problem was a variable group created in the project for provider block.  Despite it appearing to authenticate correctly,  deleting and recreating the variable group, fixed this problem.

I had quadruple checked them to ensure they matched existing projects, and they were fine.  I had copied and pasted from a working project too originally.  I just copied and pasted the values back in, from that same project, and it started working.   So, very, annoying.